# How can I delete the first 16 records on a List?

Tags: python, list

I want to get just 16 records and if there more than 16, then delete the first 16 from the list.

my code:

```
ItemList = {
    "items": [
        [
            [19,1],[19,2],[19,3],[19,4],[19,5],[19,6],[19,7],[19,8],[19,9],[19,10],[19,11],[19,12],[19,13],[19,14],[19,15],[19,16],[19,17],[19,18],[19,19],[19,20],[19,21],[19,22],[19,23],[19,24],[19,25],[19,26],[19,27],[19,28],[19,29],[19,30],[19,31],[19,32], 
        ],
        [],
        [],
    ],
}

if len(ItemList["items"][0]) > 16:
    for index in xrange(16):
        ItemList["items"][0].remove(ItemList["items"][0][index])
print ItemList["items"][0]
```

but it doesn't work

this is my output:

```
[[19, 2], [19, 4], [19, 6], [19, 8], [19, 10], [19, 12], [19, 14], [19, 16], [19, 18], [19, 20], [19, 22], [19, 24], [19, 26], [19, 28], [19, 30], [19, 32]]
```

I just want to get this:

```
[[19,17],[19,18],[19,19],[19,20],[19,21],[19,22],[19,23],[19,24],[19,25],[19,26],[19,27],[19,28],[19,29],[19,30],[19,31],[19,32]]
```

Comment: You can just use slicing

Comment: I got a solution:

for x in xrange(len(ItemList["items"][0])/16-1):
    del ItemList["items"][0][:16]
print ItemList["items"][0]

but its the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edit after comment)
May be this is what you are looking for:

```
if len(ItemList['items'][0]) > 16:
    ItemList['items'][0] = ItemList['items'][0][-16:]
```

---

You can use this:

```
ItemList['items'][0] = ItemList['items'][0][16:]
```

Comment: the only problem is that multiple entries are made ​​, always by 16

i want to delete the first 16 records or get the last 16

Comment: @Noa502 this comment of yours doesn't say the same thing as your question. In question you said if there are more than 16, then delete the first 16. Now if there are say 17 elements, deleting first 16 will result in only 1 remaining. But according to the above comment you want to get the last 16. So what actually do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
del ItemList["items"][0][:16]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use slices:

```
>>> ItemList['items'][0][16::]
[[19, 17], [19, 18], [19, 19], [19, 20], [19, 21], [19, 22], [19, 23], [19, 24], [19, 25], [19, 26], [19, 27], [19, 28], [19, 29], [19, 30], [19, 31], [19, 32]]
```